# MS Excel: insert a row automatically if the content in a cell is <> that in cell of the last row?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a row automatically if the content in a cell is not the same as that in the cell of the last row?

e.g. B1 contains "K1234", B2 contain "K1235" then add a emply row between line 1 & line 2, so B2 become B3.  After that, continue to check column B of the whole worksheet.

If B5 contains "K2345" and B6 contains "K2345", then no need to do anything but continous to check column B for the whole worksheet.

Comment: If you have some code that isn't quite working or throwing errors, please show it.  If you don't have any code, chances are that this question will be closed.

Answer (score -2):

Hi @Anita I'm suggesting you a bttr on, has more variety,, try this,, ☺

Sub InsertRowsAsValueChange()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Insert Range"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox( "Range" , xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1

If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then

WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

NB :When you run this will show inputbox to insert data range.

Hope this help u.